# Migration in TFS 2017 from Scrum to Agile

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to migrate all data from Scrum dashboard in TFS 2017 to Agile board with all history automatically?

Comment: Is there anyfeedback, What kind of data you want to move, workitems or other data?

Comment: Backlog, stories, work items etc.

Comment: If the target team project and source team project are under the same collection, you don't have to migrate workitems and also could see them on target team project's dashboard. Please see the **update** of my reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dashboard are not support to migrate. You'd better tell what specify data you want to migrate.

For on-premises TFS, process template are also not support to change. But in VSTS, you could [change the process template of a team project](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/backlogs/remove-delete-work-items#change-the-work-item-type).

**Update:**

Workitems does not support to move from one team project to another. But if the source team project and the target team project are in the same collection, the workitems of source team project could be accessed in target team projects without migration.

In the target team project, create a query to find out workitems in source team project. Then create a chart for this new query and add it to dashboard of target team project.

[image]